# Filtering asynchronous data and reflecting data into table

Tags: angular, typescript, web

**Context**

I am creating a web application in Angular 11 and I am using asynchronous data received from a specific back-end server. I am receiving the data from the back-end and I am subscribing to it in order for it to reflect into my table view. Now I want to implement a filter feature that filters based on a certain predicate (in this case row name).

**Problem statement**

There are issues when I try to make changes in the filtered list, once the filtering is done and I remove the predicate in the text input form, the table is being repopulated by the "this.ngOnInit()" function. It does not incorporate any changes made to the object, as it is being reloaded from the back end server again.

**Source code of the problem:**

```
components: Comp[] = [];
searchComponent: any

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.load();
}

private load(): void {
    this.componentService.getComponents().subscribe(component => {
        this.components = component;
    }, error => {
    console.error(`${error}`);
    });
}

searchAvailable(): void {
    if (this.searchComponent === '') {
        this.ngOnInit();
    } else {
        this.components = this.components.filter(comp => {
             return comp.Komponente.toLocaleLowerCase().match(this.searchComponent.toLocaleLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Presentation code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter"
           [(ngModel)]="searchComponent"
           (ngModelChange)="searchAvailable()" #filter>
```

Table filling:

```
<tr *ngFor="let component of components>
```

**Result I am looking for:**

My goal is to be able to filter the observable list based on a given predicate, make some changes in the received list and incorporate that back into the original list in order to view the list in the table.

What would be an approach to fix this and persist the correct data into the table? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: You already have all the data you need on the client, reloading data again after search input is cleared is not necessary. I'd add a field to the objects result set like isVisible and change that flag based on the query and show or hide on the client side based on the new flag. This way your changes will persist and you don't have to load the data all the time.

Comment: Hey @arunes could you elaborate on that? I do not get what you mean by show and hide on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample app for you, [see the full working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6zqxaf)

So the final code looks something like this, hope it helps.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Comp } from './component.model';
import { ComponentService } from './component.service';

interface VComp extends Comp {
  isVisible: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  components: VComp[] = [];
  query: string;

  constructor(private componentService: ComponentService) {
    this.load();
  }

  private load(): void {
    this.componentService.getComponents().subscribe(
      component => {
        this.components = component.map(c => {
          return { ...c, isVisible: true };
        });
      },
      error => {
        console.error(`${error}`);
      }
    );
  }

  doSearch(): void {
    if (!this.query) {
      this.components.forEach(c => (c.isVisible = true));
      return;
    }

    this.components.forEach(c => {
      const match = c.name.match(new RegExp(this.query, 'i')); // for case insensitive search
      c.isVisible = !!match;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arunes for your elaborate example! I will try this out tomorrow morning. I will get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @arunes I managed to fix it. Just to be clear, the main idea behind your solution is that only the rows where the component is marked as .isVisible are displayed using "*ngIf=component.isVisible" right? I think it is a clever solution, I did not look at it this way.

Comment: @Guusda Yes that's correct, you don't want to put an unnecessary load on the server. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

With @arunes solution I managed to implement a filter function correctly.